# Multiple connection strings in asp.net core using dapper

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Hi I want to inject 2 database connection strings into the repository constructor.
like

```
var myDb = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:MyDb").Value;            
services.AddSingleton<ITokenRepo>(new TokenRepo(myDb));
```

I am passing one string here but I want to pass 2 different database strings.
I can do by passing IConfiguration to the constructor but I want without that.
my TokenRepo is like this

```
public class TokenRepo : ITokenRepo
{
    private readonly string _connectionA;
    private readonly string _connectionB;
    private readonly IErrorHandling _error;
    public TokenRepo(string connectionA, string connectionB)
    {
        _connectionA = connectionA;           
        _connectionA = connectionA;
        _error = new ErrorHandling();
    }
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DatabaseA": "Server=sql123;Database=Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=appUser;Password=123456;Application Name=ABC",
"DatabaseB": "Server=sql123;Database=DEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=appUser;Password=123456;Application Name=DEF"
```

},

Comment: why dont you parameterize TokenRepo constructor to pass both of them? there are multiple ways of handling this. what is your intention?

Comment: I want data from different databases in the TokenRepo. My token repo is like this.                 public class TokenRepo : ITokenRepo
    {
        private readonly string _connectionA;
        private readonly string _connectionB;
        private readonly IErrorHandling _error;
        public TokenRepo(string connectionA, string connectionB)
        {
            _connectionA = connectionA;           
            _connectionA = connectionA;
            _error = new ErrorHandling();
        }

Comment: Did mean you want to parse two db connection from one string of `Configuration` in the TokenRepo  constructor? Post the content of `ConnectionStrings:MyDb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to do it like this:

```
var databaseA = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DatabaseA").Value;
var databaseB = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DatabaseB").Value;

services.AddSingleton<ITokenRepo>(new TokenRepo(databaseA, databaseB));
```